# ASP.NET Core MVC / ASP.NET Web API / ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, xamarin, asp.net-core-mvc

Если честно, я запутался в том, что предлагает Microsoft. Подскажите что мне нужно, в каком направлении двигаться чтобы не потратить зря время. Объясню задачу, у меня есть готовое приложение Xamarin для которого нужен бэкэнд:

- Небольшая админ. панель управления (с веб интерфейсом);
- Регистрация / авторизация с подтверждением по email;
- Пользователи могут 
  просматривать/добавлять/изменять данные из Xamarin приложения (профили, рейтинги и т.п.);
- Взаимодействие в реальном времени с помощью SignalR.

Возможно в дальнешем понадобится сделать фронт для этого бэкэнда.
Пожалуйста, разъясните, что нужно использовать?

На сколько я сам понимаю, что весь фунционал админ панели это ASP.NET Core MVC, для общения с приложениям дополнительно нужно API к нему (как-то крепить?) и ещё SignalR......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно **ASP.NET Core MVC**, дополнительно ничего не нужно "крепить".
MVC и Web API это просто подходы к разработке, весь функционал Web API будет в проекте с типом MVC, можно создавать проект с типом Empty и настраивать под себя, но для упрощения рутины вы можете выбрать что вам более подходит (в вашем случае - MVC).

- по SignalR есть подробный гайд тут:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
- Тут информация по клиенту, для использования в мобильном приложении:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio